# GAM - crear dos usuarios con el mismo email

Tags: genexus

En una KB integrada con GAM en Genexus17 U6, al intentar crear un usuario con un email que ya existe, sale la siguiente validación propia de GAM:

```
Ya existe un usuario registrado con ese correo electrónico, seleccione otro. (GAM78)
```

¿Existe alguna forma de configurar que se puedan dar de alta dos usuarios con el mismo mail o quitar esta validación?

Los usuarios se están dando de alta con el siguiente código:

```
&User.Name          = &Name
&User.EMail         = &EMail
&User.FirstName     = &FirstName
&User.LastName      = &LastName
&User.Password      = &Password
&User.MustChangePassword = true
&User.Save()

If &User.Success()
  Commit
  ...
Else
  &Errors = &User.GetErrors()
  Do 'DisplayMessages'
  Endif
EndIf
```

Entiendo que esta validación es interna de GAM y se ejecuta en el &User.Save()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como estas?

Si, se puede.
Si vas a la configuracion del GAM, en gamhome, podes cambiar la configuracion de identificador de usuario. Vas a **Settings > Repository Configuration**, luego vas al tab **Users**, y ahi seleccionas el identificador de usuario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Perfecto, cuando pongo que sea solo por Name me aparece otra opción que es "User email is unique?" y destildando eso puedo dar de alta usuarios con el mismo mail.